# capture live frames in hd during video capture in canon camera with EDSDK

Tags: c#, camera, edsdk, canon-sdk

i am developing a desktop app for accessing canon camera with EDSDK.

capturing original video on sending command to camera is saving too 200 mb video of 10 seconds.it takes too much time to copy this vidoe to pc.
so currently i am capturing frames of live preview and save it to local pc and generating video from these frames using ffmpeg.
but live preview frames are very low resolution.
is it possible to capture frames of video capture(not preview) and save it to pc?
OR Aany another solution to save or generate video in high resolution in low time to get it in pc.

is there any solution for my problem?i want to capture video in high resolution and it should not be much time taking .